# Stroke animation efect on keyframes doesn't work on a SVG in Internet Explorer, why?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a problem with following (sample) code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @keyframes alert {
      0% {
        stroke: red
      }
      50% {
        stroke: transparent
      }
      100% {
        stroke: red
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes alert {
      0% {
        stroke: red
      }
      50% {
        stroke: transparent
      }
      100% {
        stroke: red
      }
    }
    .item-400-rect-active {
      animation: alert 2s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: alert 2s infinite;
      stroke: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <svg>
    <rect class="item-400-rect-active" style="fill: yellow;" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" />
  </svg>
  <html>
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but it does nothing in IE11 (other animations work fine, for example changing border color of div element). I can't figure why this is not working.